# Is Myocarditis infectious?

Tags: infection, heart-disease, heart

How can Myocarditis spread from a person who has it?
Is touching a person who died of Myocarditis dangerous?

Comment: Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require prior research information when asking questions. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't find anything related to this on Google. I know, from Google, that it is spread mainly through virus, but nowhere do they mention how contagious this disease is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Myocarditis](https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/myocarditis/symptoms-causes/syc-20352539) itself is not a virus nor is it contagious - the term refers an [inflammation of the myocardium](https://www.bhf.org.uk/informationsupport/conditions/myocarditis) (a.k.a. the heart muscle). A viral infection is probably the most common cause of myocarditis but there's many different viruses that can have it as a complication including:

- Adenovirus (the common cold)
- Hepatitis B/C
- Parvovirus
- HIV
- Rubella

the list goes on. It can also result from a bacterial infection (staph, strep, diptheria etc) parasites, fungal infections, or as a reaction to an environmental factors such as a drugs, medication, carbon monoxide, radiation.

So Myocarditis itself isn't transmissible but the some of the conditions that cause it might be - so any precautions required to prevent catching the contagion that caused the myocarditis apply. That said it's quite a rare complication and not always serious - and there's no saying that because one person developed it as a result of a given disease that anyone they infect will get it as well.